# Does winston jump further when looking up?

Tags: overwatch

Does winston jump **further** when looking up?
I've noticed I've been able to hop over ledges and land on top of buildings if I look up.

But in addition to the height, it seems as though the distance is furthered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Winston always jumps in the direction he's looking, so by looking up you're going to be jumping straight up instead of forward. So no, you're definitely not jumping farther by looking straight up.

As always, the angle that will land you farthest from the starting point is 45°, so look "halfway" up if you just want to cover as much distance as possible on a flat plane.

Comment: Can you confirm this? That is to say, is it proven that the initial velocity of Winson's jump is constant and not a function of the angle at which he is jumping?

Comment: @nasukkin Yes? That's why I answered the question. It also takes around 40 seconds to test in the Practice Range.